# Kivy basics- Invalid syntax

Tags: python, android, kivy

I am trying to start with Kivy, but it's demotivating just at the beginning. I tried few of the solutions, but none of them worked. Anything that might work?

import kivy

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class DemoApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label(text="Lets mine")

DemoApp().run()
```

I get following error:

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\RUDY RYC\.kivy\logs\kivy_21-05-22_5.txt
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.gstreamer" 0.3.2
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.angle" 0.3.0
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew" 0.3.0
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2" 0.3.1
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.0.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\Users\RUDY RYC\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.9.5 (tags/v3.9.5:0a7dcbd, May  3 2021, 17:27:52) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\Users\RUDY RYC\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe"
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 186 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_pil (img_sdl2, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: pil(['text_sdl2'] ignored)
[CRITICAL] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider. Please enable debug logging (e.g. add -d if running from the command line, or change the log level in the config) and re-run your app to identi
fy potential causes
sdl2 - ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _window_sdl2: Nie można odnaleźć określonego modułu.
  File "C:\Users\RUDY RYC\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 58, in core_select_lib
    mod = __import__(name='{2}.{0}.{1}'.format(
  File "C:\Users\RUDY RYC\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from kivy.core.window._window_sdl2 import _WindowSDL2Storage

[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
```

Comment: Your problem isn't invalid syntax, it's that your kivy isn't installed properly. Did you follow the instructions on the kivy website? What command did you use to install it?

Comment: python -m pip install --upgrade pip wheel setuptools
python -m pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 kivy.deps.sdl2 kivy.deps.glew
python -m pip install kivy.deps.gstreamer
python -m pip install kivy.deps.angle
python -m pip install pygame
python -m pip install kivy

Comment: Try following [the instructions](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/gettingstarted/installation.html#install-kivy), especially the `kivy[base]` part.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install kivy again. It may not be properly installed